# Cordova platform add android weird issue

Tags: android, linux, cordova

I have created my Cordova app with this command:

`cordova create testapp com.example.testapp TestApp`

Then cd'd into it `cd testapp` and when trying to add the android platform: `cordova platform add android` result is below:

```
cordova platform add androidCreating android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms/android
Package: com.optie24.optie24
Name: Optie24
Android target: android-19
Copying template files...
shell.js: internal error
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'platforms/android/assets'
```

Who can help me out? It is really weird, I assume the 'platform add android' command should create the folders mentioned.

---

### Updated response:

```
cordova -d platform add android
cordova library for "android" already exists.
Checking if platform "android" passes minimum requirements...
Creating android project...
Running command: /home/arko/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create --cli /media/arko/apps/testapp/platforms/android 
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms/android
    Package: com.example.testapp
    Name: TestApp
    Android target: android-19
Copying template files...
shell.js: internal error
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'platforms/android/assets'
```

---

### Update

Still having issues with this, thought I figured out as I had set my PATH variable temporarily, but making this permanent didn't fix it. Have tried due to a suggestion of a friend to update the platform with: `cordova platform update android` but I obviously can't do that as the platform wasn't even added.

Anyone else with this issue?

Comment: try cordova -d platform add android. it gives more verbose output.
Also make sure both tools and platform tools path is been set.

Comment: @MohammedImranN please see my updated question. I have added the result there.

Comment: Check the www folder is in your testapp folder

Comment: The folder is there, it contains the folders: js, img, css and a index.html file.

Comment: is both tools and platform tools path is been set.

Comment: /usr/share/ant/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/arko/android-adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platform-tools:/home/arko/android-adt/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/tools

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52219/discussion-between-arko-elsenaar-and-mohammed-imran-n)

Answer (score 15):

Just change the permissions for your phonegap app directory.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 <path_to_phonegap_dir>
```

Then just cd to you phonegap directory and run the app.

```
phonegap local run android
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

It's related to a known issue:

https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues/123

You can workaround by creating an empty folder called "platforms" within your app directory.